# return HTML output to python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, return, return-value

I'm building a local website in python to press a button, so the door to my room will open from my phone by using a raspberry pi. I already have made a python program, which, if ran, will open the door flawlessly, however, I am trying to make a button in HTML that will return something to execute the file which will open the door.

This is what I already have:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from test import open_door

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/open/door')
def doorOpen():
    return render_template('door.html')

@app.route('/opendoor')
def openDoor():
    open_door()
    return 'the door should be open'


if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Here is test.py the file which will open the door if executed, and door.html is the following:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="/opendoor" class="openbutton">Open for me please</a>
</body>
</html>
```

It is not something fancy but it only has to work for now.
It looks to me like the return is not doing anything since i also added a return and a print function in the openDoor() function withouth any response.
I couln't find any awnsers on the internet so i am curious what the problem is!

p.s. This is my first time with python and i am a beginner with HTML 
edit: this is test.py:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

testPin = 18

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(testPin, GPIO.OUT)

counter =0

def open_door():
    try:
        while counter < 900000:
            GPIO.output(testPin, GPIO.HIGH)

            counter += 1

    except:
        print ("Everything is oke!")

    finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an onclick function, you can route the button to another page on your localhost:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from test import open_door
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def doorOpen()
   return render_template('door.html')

@app.route('/opendoor')
def openDoor():
   open_door()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

In `door.html`:

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="/opendoor" class="openbutton">Open Door</a>
</body>
</html>
```

In the HTML file, `class="openbutton"` is for pure styling purposes.

Comment: `<a href="/opendoor">Open Door</a>` should work, and doesn't require knowledge of the hostname.

Comment: I get the message that test() is not defined. Can't find anywhere on how to make it run another file

Comment: @Kuunnn `test()` is a function call for demonstration in this code. To run the code in `test.py`, you have to import the file and call whatever main function exists in the file. What functions are written in `test.py`?

Comment: @Ajax1234 I made use of a "try:" function with a while loop in it. Followed by "except:" function with a print in it to test if it worked. After that, a "finally: GPIO.cleanup()"

Comment: @Kuunnn Encapsulate the code you have above in a function called `open_door`, which can then be imported to the flask app. Please see my recent edit for more info.

Comment: @Ajax1234 I placed in the /opendoor path the "import test" function, which seems to work, but only once and not again, I'll try your new method

Comment: The signal goes to 1 when i run the app.py, and goes to 0 when I go to /opendoor after 2 seconds, so my guess is that the counter does work well with app.py

Comment: @Ajax1234 I also added the test.py